# Many aggregate functions in select query

Tags: sql

I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is so I figured I'd toss it to SO.

I'm writing a view for an application which will display some grid data based on a few tables in our database.  I know I can do this with aggregate functions in the select portion of the query, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way (possibly with sub-selects) or if this will be good enough.

Example:

```
Table A (LineItems)
--------
OrderID
Weight1
Weight2
UnitPrice

Table B (Orders)
--------
ID
```

Query example:

```
SELECT Orders.ID, SUM(LineItems.Weight1) as W1, SUM(LineItems.Weight2) as W2, ABS(SUM(LineItems.Weight1) - SUM(LineItems.Weight2)), ABS(SUM(LineItems.Weight1) - SUM(LineItems.Weight2)) FROM Orders
RIGHT OUTER JOIN LineItems ON Orders.ID = OrderLines.OrderID
WHERE Orders.RecordDeleted <> 'TRUE'
GROUP BY Orders.ID
```

To clarify, this is just a sample.  The select query will include functions for calculating price from the lineitems as well as a few other things that need to be used in aggregate functions (all pretty basic math operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are grouping using the same column you should be to go. Unfortunately it is not the case if you want to group on different columns. The counts will be narrowed to the whole list of the `GROUP BY`, for example if you want to group by `OrderLines.ID` as well.

For a better performance, I would use calculated columns in the `Orders` table.

First you need to create a user defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetOrderWeight(@Key int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT SUM(Weight1)
        FROM LineItems
        WHERE OrderID = @Key
    )
END
```

Then add a calculated column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders ADD OrderWeight AS dbo.GetOrderWeight(ID)
```

Follow with the same for other aggregate methods you have. Please be aware that this is a performance killer if used with function that has `varchar(max)` as input parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

This is should be more effective then using subselects.

Just be sure that you have proper indexes to get the best performance.